# How can I create objects in Python via iterating through a string?

Tags: python, string, object, iteration, character

I read in a line from a **file** as such:

```
a b c d e f
```

With this string, I want to turn each letter into a new "user" in my user class. So what I want is something like:

```
for character in **the first line of the file**:
    if character != ' '
        user = user(character)
```

In other words, I would want something like "userA = user("a")", where user is a class I defined to take in a string as a parameter.

I'm having a hard time finding ways to iterate strings in Python with regard to a file, and then using the result to create an object.

Comment: you probably want A = user('a'), B= user('b') ? ...

Comment: so you want a set of variables usera = 'a', etc.  This could be done using `eval` but I would question the usefulness.  Just use a dict where `user['a'] = User( 'a' )`

Comment: Yes. I'll look into using a dict as the posted answer suggests.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have an addition on the left hand side of an assignment (you cannot construct variale names that way). You should use a dictionary and the `str.split` method:

```
users = {} # note the plural, this is not 'user', but 'users'
for name in myString.split():
    users[name] = user(name)
```

You can also use a dictionary comprehension to achieve the same:

```
users = { name : user(name) for name in myString.split() }
```

Comment: The initial string is the result of myFile = open('file.txt.), and then myFilfe = myFile.readline(). I'm having trouble using split on myFile.

Comment: What sort of trouble are you having?  You should not do  myFilfe = myFile.readline() because you loose the file object, which is a bit naughty. It is best closed explicitly

Comment: `accessControls = open('access.txt', 'r')
    usersString = accessControls.readline();
    
    users = {}
    for username in accessControls.split():
        users[username] = user(name)`

My error is: AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: `for username in usersString.split():`

Comment: Whoops, that's right. Sorry to keep bugging you, but now I'm getting TypeError: 'module' object is not callable -- does that have to do with the way I tried to create the objects?

Comment: No that's beacaues you put `(...)` after the name of a module. Note that `user` might be a module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/user.html